# ajax - injecting specific elements throughout the DOM

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using ajax to inject new content into a placeholder div in my html page with id #content_wrap. This pretty much replaces everything below the header, but obviously does not refresh the page. This works great, but I also have a few elements in my header that I'd like to update with data that the php doc grabs from my database. Right now my php doc is putting together a big chunk of HTML and inserting ALL OF IT into the dom in my html page. Is it possible to pick and choose certain pieces created by the php doc and then insert them into specific elements in my header (without injecting a whole new header)? Can I use the same php doc to create the different elements I want to insert into multiple locations (#content_wrap div AND some divs in my header)? Or is it all or nothing injection? I'm new to this but have gotten this far reading other questions and responses!

```
var xmlhttp;    
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      //set a state change listener to recognize when the AJAX call is complete
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        //if complete, inject html in form of responseText into the content wrap div
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("content_wrap").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
      }

//fire ajax call, with some variables I need to pass to the php doc
      xmlhttp.open("GET","nextq.php?fbid="+fbid+"&c="+cat+"&yaynay="+yaynay+"&response_id="+response_id,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: are you talking about the request/response headers, the `<head></head>` section or some page header like `<div id="header"></div>`?

Comment: Instead of this : `document.getElementById("content_wrap").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` Send the response from the php as an name/value pair array converted to JSON. Then when you get the response you can pick and choose where you want to display each name/value pair content.

Comment: @andrew sorry I did not specify.. it is the latter (<div id="header"></div>). Although really it's more like: <div id="header"> <div id="insert_here">this is where I want to inject content</div></div<

Comment: then what @stackErr said is the best approach, you should search on json encoding th ajax response and set different html elements to be different properties of the response

Comment: Some advice: do not use xmlhttp object directly, use a small library such as ajax.js which fixes the many cross-browser issues behind ajax.

Comment: one more thing before I go down that path... you say I'll be able to set different html elements to be different properties of the response which is great, but will I also be able to set class names of the html elements themselves?

Comment: @Christian - what would that look like? I guess I have to link to that library in my <head>, but how would my syntax change in the snippet I provided above?

Comment: @bkopp It depends on the library. For example, if you use jQuery, it would look like: `jQuery.get("nextq.php", {fbid:fbid,c:cat,yaynay:yaynay,response_id:response_id, function(){ alert('hi'); });`

Comment: ok cool I looked up jquery .get() and I think that should work great. thanks for the tip! I already have a jquery library loaded, so I guess I just need to load an ajax library too.